# How to prevent bouncing off the wall when moving against it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is, that when Im moving against a wall, that there is a little bouncing effect. Here is a video of it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t5drxu4aw60nq59/meem.mp4?dl=0

I dont know how to fix it, I already tried everything. I hope someone know a solution for this. Thank you
Here is the movement script:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    public float x;
    public float y;

    public bool canMove;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (canMove)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                GoUp();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                GoDown();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                GoRight();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                GoLeft();
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                GoUp();
                GoRight();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                GoUp();
                GoLeft();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                GoDown();
                GoRight();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                GoDown();
                GoLeft();
            }
            this.transform.position = new Vector2(this.transform.position.x + x, this.transform.position.y + y);
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
    }

    public void GoUp()
    {
        y = Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }

    public void GoDown()
    {
        y = Time.deltaTime * (-speed);
    }

    public void GoRight()
    {
        x = Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }

    public void GoLeft()
    {
        x = Time.deltaTime * (-speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that you stopping your movement with a collider, so if you still going rigth, you keep on colliding and bouncing back.
You can handle the distance to the wall and stop going right when that distance reaches 0, that would mean that you collided, so that you stop going right with a `bool`. Or you can handle that same boolean, with [OntriggerEnter()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) to stop going right (or wherever) when the player in inside (touching) a determined trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find two suggestions to handle stop going right example. Note they are going to be not debugued code, as I dont know your project details. Also no the most correct in many aspects for the saem reason. Just to give you the idea.

1.- With distance control

```
public GameObject wall; //ref to wall set in editor
float playerHalfSize = 0f;
float wallHalfSize = 0f; 
float bodiesTotDist = 0f;
Start() {
    playerHalfSize = transform.scale.x / 2;
    wallHalfSize = wall.scale.x / 2; // supposing size is set with scale. Preferably get the size with a collider or the mesh renderer Bounds class inside the respective collider or MeshRenderer classes
    bodiesTotDist = playerHalfSize + wallHalfSize;
}

float getDistanceToWall(wall) {
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, wall.transform.position) - bodiesTotDist; 
}

public void GoRight()
{
    if (getDistanceToWall() > 0) //this avoids your player x move further to the right
        x = Time.deltaTime * speed;
}
```

If you might still see the bouncing you can try to adjust manually a threshold distance, for example `getDistanceToWall() > 0.5f` or adjunting the collider.

2.- With a trigger: If you put a trigger a little bit bigger that your wall, when the wall touches the player you can handle in the code also to avoid further `x` right set.

```
bool isRightWallTouching = false;
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject == wall) //for the right wall
    isRightWallTouching = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    isRightWallTouching = false;
}

public void GoRight()
{
if (isRightWallTouching  > 0) //this avoids your player x move further to the right
    x = Time.deltaTime * speed;
}
```

As told, not debugged code so might have some failures and the chance that you might have many walls, so this suggestion may lead to a lots of bools dirty solution, but hope it can provide you some inspiration to put your game to work and move on :)